# getting undefined variable error in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, migration

I have two models: **Hotel** and **Comment**, along with their respective migration inside hotel there is a function:

**Hotel Model:**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Hotel extends Model
{
    public function Comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

**Comment Model:**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function hotel(){
        return $this->belongsTo(hotel::class);
    }
}
```

When I am using tinker, I get the correct result, but when I use `{{$hotel->name}}` to show the name of the hotel present in table, it will show an error `Undefined variable`.

**Error:**

```
(2/2) ErrorException

Undefined variable: hotel (View: /var/www/html/tpfl/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

Comment: How is it passed to the view from the controller?

Comment: Are you passing the $hotel variable from the controller to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `$hotel` is an initialized object by doing this:

```
$hotel = new hotel();
$hotel->name;
```